# How to add Values of multiple Select Cases

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a vb.net program that runs a stored procedure on a database.  After I build the dataset, i'm scanning the table inside the dataset searching for specific information.  I used Select Case statements to find the correct info.  The problem i'm running into is I can't figure out how to display my results as a "sum".  I know that it's because i'm using "For Each" but i'm unsure how to assign "Result" to ds.tables(0).Rows

Code:

```
For Each Result As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Select Case Result("Report")
                Case "TOTALS"
                    Select Case Result("Description")
                        Case "Coupons", "Coupons Tax-Free", "GC"
                            MsgBox(Result("netAmt"))
                    End Select

            End Select
        Next
```

As coded i'm receiving 3 message boxes.  The first one:

```
"15"
```

The Second One:

```
"10"
```

The Third:

```
"5"
```

I'd prefer to see the sum of all 3 found:

```
"30"
```

How can I retrieve the sum of these, keeping in mind it's possible that one of the 3 comes back as 0 in some cases

Comment: Since you're doing it in VB.NET, why not you just sum up the numbers yourself?

Comment: Where is `ds.Tables(0)` coming from? If it's a database, it's best to let the DB engine do the aggregation.

Comment: It is a datatable.  I'll use this eventually to pull 10 different pieces of information.  If I let the db engine to the aggregation, i'll have to write 10 different queries using the same stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional variable which will store a sum e.g.:

```
Dim numberOfStudents As Integer = 0
```

Then instead of displaying the current net amount add it to the current sum:

```
sum = sum + FoundRow("netAmt")
```

To simplify I assumed that `FoundRow` returns a number. However, if it returns for example a string you will have to parse it in the following way: `Integer.Parse(FoundRow("netAmt"))`.

Finally, after the for each loop, display the result:

```
MsgBox(sum)
```

Comment: This is great.  I used your SUM idea